# Is there a way to create a .net project in eclipse using no template

Tags: .net, eclipse, ubuntu

I have eclipse 2021 installed on my laptop which is running Ubuntu 20.04 and I have .net 6 installed with snap when I go to create a .net project it says no template selected it in preferences the .net folder is in the snap folder. I just want to create a blank project , how can I do this. [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX8rE.png)

Comment: Same problem, did you have an answer since then ?